# Where to store return messages for javascript?

Tags: javascript, return, message

Where should I store message types javascript function is returning? I can just return string messages, but it seems like a bad idea. Are there any best practices?

For example in this kind of function (of course real functions make more sense then this)

```
function isFooValid(foo){
   if(foo.length < 4){ 
     return "TOO_SHORT";
   } else if(foo.length >100) {
     return "TOO_LONG";
   } else if(foo.charAt(1) == 'A'){
     return "THERE_SHOULD_NOT_BE_SECOND_CHARACTER_A";
   }
}
```

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to return a string?  What's the problem here?

Comment: Can you explain why what you have already is not sufficient? If you care about internationalisation or re-use then you can create a globally-defined array of messages that can be switched out or modified in one place. But that's obvious, so what are you really asking?

Comment: By the way, a function named `isFooValid` should return `true` or `false`, not some string.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You can return `object` intead of string. `return {valid: false, message: "TOO_SHORT"};`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The problem is that, in my opinion, such messages should be at one place. E.g. in android we have strings resource files, or in java property files. I wondered if I there were any best practices for javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable for that. For example you can have:

```
myMessages ={
    "secondChar": "THERE_SHOULD_NOT_BE_SECOND_CHARACTER_A",
    "tooShort": "TOO_SHORT"
}
```

Then you can retrieve them as `myMessages.tooShort`, for example.

Even, if you want to have something similar to the string resources in android, you can store all the strings in a json file. If you load it before you js script, you are going to have the `myMessages` var available.